# Tableau Prep - What is the best way to join/manage pivoted data sets (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, tableau-prep

I've created some manual entry sheets for people to manually enter some values under the respective month against their buildings for 2 levels of detail

Sheet 1 = No. of people on site
Sheet 2 = No. of people off site

Both tables have the same structure of

Column A Header = Building (building names below)
Column B - M Header = Jan to Dec Months

In Tableau Prep, I have pivoted the data so that I have the date as a column so that I have 12 entries by building (each building having 12 months of their respective data) and this works as standalone outputs when I complete the workflow

Where the challenge is, when I try to join them I get double sets of months and building names where in fact I only need 1 of each but both of the values for the on site and off site.

I've tried removing them from the flow with a clean step but still get an odd aggregation of month totals when I try to use the data in Tableau Server

Are there better ways to join pivoted data together that would make the output more sensible?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. First, I'm trying to understand the role of Google Sheets in your scenario. It _sounds_ as if you importing the Sheets data into Tableau and then doing all the data manipulation (pivot tables, etc) in Tableau. Is that right? If so, I'm wondering whether this question should be tagged for `Sheets`. Second, it would help (regardless of Sheets Vs Tableau) to include some sample data in your question as well as an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve.